# Big performance issue using TextWrapping and ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, word-wrap

I have the following piece of XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When I resize the Window where the `ScrollViewer` is placed I have a very big performance issue: the window freezes for a few seconds!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried a profiler? As an alternative you could break into the debugger when the freeze does happen and post the call stack here.

Comment: How much text in the TextBlock?

Comment: @spender About 6000 characters.

Comment: @AloisKraus The call stack does not give you any information [External Code].

Comment: Check in the Debug tab of your project settings Enable unmanaged code debugging and load the symbols from the symbol servers to see what is going on.

Comment: I figure that you don't have this problem is the textblock is not doing the wrapping... have you tried another control which is designed to hold a lot of characters, like the RichTextBox (you can disable editing for it to behave like a textblock.

Comment: Use RichTextBox and skip the outer ScrollViewer. I believe ScrollViewer would provide infinite space for the TextBlock and put scroll bars in the direction where TextBlock overflows

Answer (score 0):

if it is possible and has sense, try to change target framework to 4 or higher(on project property page). it helps sometime. CLR 4 is much more fast.